# How to stop playback?

Tags: java

```
public class Jxplay extends Thread {

File f;

public Jxplay(File f){

    this.f=f;

}

public void run(){

    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        Player jx = new Player(fis);
        jx.play();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

How to stop playback ?

Comment: What is this Player component, JMF javax.media.Player or proprietary bean? EDIT: You probably mean http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html component?

Comment: I am using JLayer1.0.1 mp3 plugin jar for java

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057214/jlayer-pause-and-resume-song ?

Comment: Since it is run in thread you may need to set a class variable and conditionally stop the thread upon hitting an event.